# Redux mock store only returning one action when multiple actions are dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-mock-store

I'm trying to mock this axios call:

```
export const fetchCountry = (query) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchCountryPending());
    return axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/countries/?search=${query}`)
      .then(response => {
        const country = response.data;
        dispatch(fetchCountryFulfilled(country));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(fetchCountryRejected());
        dispatch({type: "ADD_ERROR", error: err});
      })
  }
}
```

Which on a successful call, should dispatch both action creators fetchCountryPending() and fetchCountryFullfilled(country). When I mock it like so:

```
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

// Async action tests
describe('country async actions', () => {
  let store;
  let mock;

  beforeEach(function () {
    mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    store = mockStore({ country: [], fetching: false, fetched: true })
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    mock.restore();
    store.clearActions();
  });

  it('dispatches FETCH_COUNTRY_FULFILLED after axios request', () => {
    const query = 'Aland Islands'
    mock.onGet(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/countries/?search=${query}`).replyOnce(200, country)
    store.dispatch(countryActions.fetchCountry(query))
    const actions = store.getActions()
    console.log(actions)
    expect(actions[0]).toEqual(countryActions.fetchCountryPending())
    expect(actions[1]).toEqual(countryActions.fetchCountryFulfilled(country))
  });
});
```

The second expect fails and console.log(actions) only shows an array with the one action, but it should contain both actions, fetchCountryPending and fetchCountrySuccess. When I log ('dispatched'), it shows the second action is getting dispatched in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get a then(() => {}) block to work but I was able to await the function and make it async:

```
  it('dispatches FETCH_COUNTRY_FULFILLED after axios request', async () => {
    const query = 'Aland Islands'
    mock.onGet(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/countries/?search=${query}`).replyOnce(200, country)
    await store.dispatch(countryActions.fetchCountry(query))
    const actions = store.getActions()
    console.log(actions)
    expect(actions[0]).toEqual(countryActions.fetchCountryPending())
    expect(actions[1]).toEqual(countryActions.fetchCountryFulfilled(country))
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try making your it block async and dispatch the action. I believe the tests are running before your get requests return the value

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but not how to go about it

Comment: Await your function fetchCountry and pass in dispatch as an argument like await(fetchCountry(query)(dispatch)).                            Sorry im on my phone and cant format it correctly

Comment: after I dispatched, I moved the expect into a then(() => block, which is fixing it, but now the GET request I'm mocking is getting rejected? When I comment out mock.onGet(), I'm getting the same result, so I don't even think my GET request is being mocked

Comment: I use sinon to stub my get requests to return a resolving promise . Give it a shot and see if that works